# Разрешения экрана

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Я вчера установил на virtualbox linux ubuntu 12.04 ничего не понимаю вопрос в том что разрешение экрана 640×480.
Вопрос как его изменить если при вводе 
терминал команды `xrandr`
он выводит только
`640×480 73.0`

---

Там оказывается была гостевая библиотека 
после установки перезагрузил система автоматически подогнала экран. Но когда я ввёл в терминал `xrandr`
Какой-то магией там появились разрешения 
`1280×706 60.0
800×600 60.0
640×480 60.0`

Откуда?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line

Comment: дрова на виртуальный видео адаптер поставить надо... или из реп `virtualbox-guest-x11` или ручками с диска идущего в комплекте с коробкой...

Comment: Откройте настройки конкретной виртуальной машины и в настройках размера видеопамяти поставьте хотя бы 64 мб (а то и все 128) + галочку 3д. Теперь можно запускать саму виртуальную  машину.